# sending clicked information stored in variable from one php site to another

Tags: php, forms

im having this variable:

```
var setValuey = function(x) {
     document.getElementById('atype').value= x; 
}
```

this refers to a clicked element:

```
<input type="hidden" name="type" value="" id="atype"><div class="person"><img src="images/voksenknap.png" onClick="setValuey('voksen')">
```

the problem is now that the set value (which happens when you click the element needs to be send to a PHP form on another site called resu.php which has this form:

```
form method="get" action="koeb.php"> 
   <fieldset><legend>Billet</legend> <table border="0"><tr> <td>Type</td><td> <input type="text" name="zone" value="<?php echo (?????);?>" readonly id="atype" style="margin-left: 20px"> </td> </tr>
```

how do i get the set value into the value field ? whenever i am writing something in the `value="<?php echo (?????);?>"` all i get is a text of an undefined variable or the text setValuey:

```
<br /><b>Notice</b>:  Undefined variable: setValuey in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\interaktion\01-company\resu.php</b> on line <b>18</b><br />
```

that is what is being written in the value field for example.

hope my description is understandable. i really need help with this.

Comment: Is the other page the one in the `action` of the first page's form?

Comment: You can't call Javascript functions in PHP. JS runs on the client, PHP runs on the server.

Answer (score 0):

The value is put into a form input. On the server, you read that with `$_POST['type']`, so it should be:

```
value="<?php echo $_POST['type']; ?>"
```